# My method is always returning false, why?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
public bool IsUser(string username)
    {
        bool user = false;
        using (var client = new datingEntities())
        {
            var result = from x in client.Person
                         select x;

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                if (item.Username == username)
                {
                    user = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return user;
    }
```

This method am I using to get data from a SQL database that I have. It's no problem with the database connection, it's just that it always is returning false even if the parameter username is existing in the database (double checked the data in the database). I tried this method before and then it worked but it don't. I'm using entity framework against my database

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint and walking through the code?

Comment: Stick a debugger on your code, stick a breakpoint on the `{` of the `foreach`, look at `item.Username` (or add code to store it in a local `string`, move the breakpoint after it and look at that) and check that it's giving you what you expect.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `return client.Person.Any(p => p.Username == username);` ?

Comment: Suspect it could be a DB collation issue - is your DB case-sensitive? See @AnandKumar's response.

Comment: You should be using .Equals() for string comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do:

```
public bool IsUser(string username)
{
    using (var entities = new datingEntities())
    {
        return entities.Person.Any(p => p.Username == username);
    }
}
```

Now you request all user entities and loop through them to see if the user matches the queried username. You should let Entity Framework or LINQ write the queries, which you do as demonstrated above.

As for the reason your function is not working: set a breakpoint, find out if any users are found at all. We can't debug that for you.

Comment: You would usualy use `return client.Persons.Any(u => u.Username == username);`

Answer (score 1):

use "ToUpper()"

```
if (item.Username.ToString().ToUpper() == username.ToUpper())
{
 user = true;
}
```

**[EDITED]**

OR use "Equal"

```
item.Equals(username, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is less good than others as mentioned in the comments, but I left it here for reference purposes.


<strike>I'm not sure why it returns false but what you are trying to achieve is usually done in the following way:</strike>

```
public bool IsUser(string username)
{
    using (var client = new datingEntities())
    {
        User user = client.Persons.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username == username);
        return user != null;
    }
}
```

This way is a lot more efficient than your way because you first pull all User records from the database to then iterate through them to find the one user with the Username equal to the provided string. My way tries to get the one record with the Username equal to the provided string, if no such record exists I return false and otherwise true.

Comment: You would usualy use `return client.Persons.Any(u => u.Username == username);`

Comment: @DanielHilgarth agree! However I tried to keep it a little more legible for the OP to understand what I am doing, matching the explanatory text below my code. I do agree with your optimisation however as it saves memory for the variable `user`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of "why am I not getting any matching values".

Comment: It is not only about the memory. Your code is different than the one from the OP. Your code throws an exception if there are multiple users with the same username. The code of the OP doesn't do that. Furthermore, `SingleOrDefault` will iterate the complete collection - except when it throws an exception - `Any` will iterate only until the condition is first met.

Comment: Why would you use Single over First or Any in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I would convert both item.UserName and username values to the lowercase and compare them this way.  This looks more reliable. Also, your linq query can be changed to avoid the loop as follows:

```
var result = from x in client.Person
             where x.UserName.ToLower() == userName.ToLower()
                         select x;
```